# Chaining an action behind an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to create a chain of actions that only happen sequentially, and not asynchronously.

It's a sign-in function, where I want the following actions to happen in this order:

- User clicks on sign in
- Sign in request sent
- If successful, data fetch is executed
- Console log that it's successful
- Then push to dashboard with fetched data

However what's actually happening is the following:

- User clicks on sign in
- Sign in request sent
- If successful, data fetch is started
- User pushed to dashboard
- Data fetch continues, and then re-renders with the data

I tried integrating async / await, but weirdly it's not doing it as I expected. I think it's me misunderstanding what I need to do more than anything.

Here's the function I want all of this to happen through:

```
const handleSignInSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        await signIn(email, password)

        console.log("Trying to push")
        history.push("/dashboard")

    }
```

And here is my sign-in function:

```
const signIn = (email, password) => {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

        .then((userCredential) => {
          var user = userCredential.user;
          setCurrentUser(user)
        })
        .then(async () => {
          console.log("Fetching data...")
          await fetchData()
        })

        .catch((error) => {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode)
          console.log(errorMessage)
        });
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I also wouldn't mix the usage of `.then` and `await`, it makes the code harder to understand and can lead to some issues, as these two ways of handling async actions behave a bit differently.

Comment: not related to the issue but why are you awaiting the result of `fetchData()` inside the callback function of the `then()` method call inside the `signIn` function? If you want to use the result of `fetchData`, you can _return_ it instead of awaiting it.

Comment: Both good comments - thanks both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `await`ing the return value of `signIn`.

`signIn` doesn't have a `return` statement so it returns `undefined`.

You can only usefully await a promise.

`return` the return value of `firebase.auth.etc.etc.catch()` which is the promise you have been working with.

Comment: Arghhhh! That's worked. Can't believe that's all I was missing, thought I was going mental. Thank you Quentin!